# How do I use iptables to forward all dns requets from a specific MAC address to a IP address?

Tags: networking, dns, iptables, forwarding

I'm not an experienced iptables user and am trying to figure out if there's a way to forward all dns requests for a specific device on my network to an external or internal webserver? Appreciate any help!

Comment: I am not sure how webserver is going to respond to dns request? Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Forward all dns requests originating from specific mac address to specific dns server?

Comment: Hi Tomek, I would like to be able to redirect a device's browser to a specified web page regardless of the dns request being made by that device's browser. So for example, if I were to type in 'www.google.com' (or any dns request for that matter) my browser would be redirected to a web page of my choosing. 

Is this possible to do this for a specific MAC address (preferred) or IP address using iptables?

Hope that's clearer.

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with Reponse Policy Zone (RPZ) in your DNS server. I don't think you can achieve this with iptables alone.